# Command line MySQL save query to xml with cdata for fields

Tags: mysql, xml, export, cdata

I'm using this command to run my sql script and save result to xml :

```
mysql -uroot -p scena --xml --default-character-set=utf8 < script.sql > result.xml
```

Some of my fields contain `HTML` and because of that, I want all of my fields to be within `cdata` so that mysql doesn't escape html when saving file.

How should I do this?